# How to move a view when you don't know its dimensions?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

What I am trying to do is animate a size & position change on an `ImageView`. To do this I use the following method:

```
void doAnimation() {
    ImageView logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
    float scaleVal = R.attr.actionBarSize / logo.getHeight(); // Finds the scale needed to make the logo as tall as the actionBar

    // Gets the width and height in dp
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpH = displayMetrics.heightPixels / density;
    float dpW = displayMetrics.widthPixels / density;

    // The final X and Y in dp
    float finalX = dpW - (logo.getWidth() / density) - 16;
    float finalY = dpH - (logo.getHeight() / density) - 16;

    // The final X and Y converted to %
    float finalXPercentage = finalX / dpW;
    float finalYPercentage = finalY / dpH;

    logo.animate()
        .setDuration(750)
        .scaleX(scaleVal)
        .scaleY(scaleVal)
        .translationX(finalXPercentage)
        .translationY(finalYPercentage);
}
```

I am calling the `doAnimation()` method from the `onResume()` method, but for obvious reasons, I cannot use `getHeight()` or `getWidth()` from within the `onResume()` method.

The problem is I don't know the height or the width of the logo as I am using a `ConstraintLayout` for it, so I do not specify the width or the height. What I am trying to do is move the `ImageView` to the top-right corner (with a 16dp space from it) and resize it to be as tall as the ActionBar (toolbar) height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `View.Post()`

```
void doAnimation() {
    ImageView logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);

    // new Runnable() can be substituted with () -> if you are using Java 8
    logo.post(new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

            // Finds the scale needed to make the logo as tall as the actionBar
            float scaleVal = 56 / (logo.getHeight() / density);

            // Gets the width and height in dp
            float width = displayMetrics.widthPixels / density;
            float height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

            // The final X and Y in dp
            float finalX = logo.getX() + width / 2;

            logo.animate()
                    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
                    .scaleX(scaleVal).scaleY(scaleVal)
                    .xBy(finalX).y(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this inside the `onLayoutChange`.I solved my issue like this.

```
logo.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        mLayout.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        doyourAnimationcodehere();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `mLayout` the layout that contains the `ImageView`?

Comment: I call this method by changing one property from the `ImageView`, correct? So far I was only able to make it change the background color of the `ConstraintLayout` to white and make the logo disappear. I used the same code as above, only inside the `onLayoutChange()` method.